# Select most recent inspection

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, select, greatest-n-per-group

I have a `ROAD_INSPECTION` table:

```
+----+------------------------+-----------+
| ID |          DATE          | CONDITION |
+----+------------------------+-----------+
|  1 | 01/01/2009             |        20 |
|  1 | 05/01/2013             |        16 |
|  1 | 04/29/2016 10:02:52 AM |        15 |
+----+------------------------+-----------+
|  2 | 01/01/2009             |         8 |
|  2 | 06/06/2012 9:55:13 AM  |         8 |
|  2 | 04/28/2015             |        11 |
+----+------------------------+-----------+
|  3 | 06/11/2012             |        10 |
|  3 | 04/21/2015             |        19 |
+----+------------------------+-----------+
```

---

What is the most efficient way to select the most recent inspection? The query would need to include the `ID` and `CONDITION` columns, despite the fact that they wouldn't `group by` cleanly:

```
+----+------------------------+-----------+
| ID |          DATE          | CONDITION |
+----+------------------------+-----------+
|  1 | 04/29/2016 10:02:52 AM |        15 |
+----+------------------------+-----------+
|  2 | 04/28/2015             |        11 |
+----+------------------------+-----------+
|  3 | 04/21/2015             |        19 |
+----+------------------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to retrieve `id` and `date` column in derived table and join the output to the main table to retrieve corresponding data from `condition` column as below.

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.date1,
       t2.CONDITION1
FROM
  (SELECT id,
          max(date1) AS date1
   FROM table1
   GROUP BY id) t1
JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
AND t1.date1 = t2.date1;
```

**Result:**

```
id  date1                  CONDITION1
-------------------------------------
1   29.04.2016 10:02:52    15
2   28.04.2015 00:00:00    11
3   21.04.2015 00:00:00    19
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/EKZEG57453)**

OR if your `rdbms` supports windows function, use below.

```
SELECT id, 
       date1, 
       condition1
FROM
  (SELECT id,
          date1,
          condition1,
          row_number() over(PARTITION BY id
                            ORDER BY date1 DESC) AS rn
   FROM table1 ) t1
WHERE rn = 1;
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/OLPGJ33050)**